# Escape ' in Python

Tags: python, git

What's the right code for this case:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["git", "log" , "-1",  "--pretty=format:\'%s %n%n%b\'", hash], 
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
message += '\n' + out
```

I always get this error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
output: Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

and I'm in the working tree.

Answer (score 6):

Since the call isn't parsed by a shell, you don't need the quotes at all:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
    ["git", "log" , "-1",  "--pretty=format:%s %n%n%b", hash],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: git use this format --pretty=format:'%s %n%n%b'" so I need ''

Comment: @user1033964: No, you don't need them.  You only need them when calling git from the shell to prevent shell processing and splitting of the parameters.  The shell will remove the quotes, and git doesn't see them.

Comment: but same error: fatal: ambiguous argument '': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: @user1033964: The error is probably due to `hash` being an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you want to include the backslashes or not so I just put this here

```
>>> s = "--pretty=format:\'%s %n%n%b\'"
>>> print s
--pretty=format:'%s %n%n%b'
>>> s2 = "--pretty=format:'%s %n%n%b'"
>>> print s2
--pretty=format:'%s %n%n%b'
>>> s3 = "--pretty=format:\\'%s %n%n%b\\'"
>>> print s3
--pretty=format:\'%s %n%n%b\'
```